# Can't declare renamed GameObject in Unity C# script

Tags: unity-game-engine

What I am trying to do is simple:

Create an empty GameObject in the [hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMeq4.png), rename it, attach a script to the main camera and use that game object. When I try to declare the object in the [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPL03.png) I am getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaE0t.png). I don't know what library I am missing or how I should make the script be aware of the created objects. I have also tried to attach the script directly to the said game object but it still won't recognize it.

This is an newly created project to help illustrate the issue.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: does KineticAudio be part of an external Library? or it lives in another namespace? Is a class made by your own?

Comment: KineticAudio is the name of the empty object I created in the hierarchy

Comment: AFAIK KinematicAudio is a script, and you are trying to reference a GameObject, try to make the reference instead of a KinematicAudio to a GO, and then you can (if you want) GetComponent<OfYourScriprt> try it and if it's not clear with this comment I will try to make a full response

Comment: The name of a gameobject does not mean you can call it. So a game object called Fred does not mean you can do Fred.transform it doesn’t know or care it’s name is Fred. That’s a human thing.

Comment: I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtiWt0SWxk8 and it seemed to be working (check 2:40). I also don't think the KinematicAudio is a script as I created it in the hierarchy with the "Create Empty" option. I am new to Unity so I might have misunderstood.

Comment: I figured it out.. He just named the object AudioSource as the type of the object he was creating... This made me think that an Object type was created automatically just by setting it's name.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in the script is declaring a type of variable called "kineticAudio", which doesn't exist. Instead, you should declare the variable of type "GameObject", because anything in the hiearchy is a game object, and kineticAudio

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MusicPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject kinetic;
    // Start is called before the first frams is called
    void Start()
    {
        
    }
    
    //Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Edit: a GameObject cannot be declared with type of the object's name, because the script doesn't know that.